# How to import util-web project to other web project

Tags: java, spring, web, deployment, fragment

Pls take a look about my problem. thank so much !

Currently I have a lot of web projects, which use different Data Base. But they have some tables which have same structure like : user, role, ... I use it for Administrator user.

And now I create a new util-web project to working with this kind of data, with some action like : add new user, delete user, add role, ...

My purpose is: use util-web project for all other web projects to control admin data.

All my web project will be deploy to one Geronimo server, and use Spring web flow framework.

Is it possible if I build util-web project to 1 file (like jar or any kind) and after that import it to all my web project ? 
If not, pls show for me your suggestion.

---

***Example*** :

I have project A and project B,... and have web-util project

Now I want the admin user of project A can connect to web-util and working with Data Base A, and the same with the user of project B and other project also. But I can not update data source of web-util every time,

I want to working like that : add project web-util as a libraty to other web projects, and when I deploy these project I can use web-util project also.
Each project have one web-util project, Is it posible ? and how can I do it ?

---

Thanks,DT

Comment: Yes this is pretty straightforward if you use a build tool like Gradle or Maven with projects dependencies configured. Essentially you can have your "util-web" project as a dependency in all other projects that require it.

Comment: Dear Invisible Arrow, thanks for your reply. For my understanding, your suggestion is : I need to set "util-web" project as a dependency in all other project, but how can the user of other project can use "util-web" project ? I can not update data source of "util-web" for every projects.

Maybe my purpose is not clear for you, sorry for that, Please take a look to my example which I already updated in my question for more detail. Thank for your support.

Comment: When project A and B (deployable web apps) depend on "util-web" project, they would package the "util-web" jar into them when they are built. Each would have a copy of the jar, so you can set any data source for each of the apps through A and B at runtime for "util-web" to use. Hope that answered your specific question. You might want to look into Gradle for managing the builds and dependenices: http://www.gradle.org/

Comment: Thank a lot Invisible Arrow for your support. Now I change the requirement, and I no need to answer this question anymore. But I think your suggestion is good idea to do it. Thanks, DT.